# Pydev + Eclipse not doing code analysis on a new project

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have several existing projects in Eclipse + Pydev and it does code analysis on them just fine.  However, I added a new project and Eclipse isn't analyzing any of the code files in it.  What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue for me. Code Analysis only works on source folders. If you created your project and haven't assigned a source... Right click on the project, and go... Properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH -> Source Folders -> Add Source Folder, and Add the project path to itself as a source.

Comment: Thank you, fixed the problem for me. Weird that this is not mentioned on the PyDev website.

Comment: No problem :) It drove me crazy.

Comment: This is a great answer. It also solves the problem of PyDev live reload not being applied after function(s) are changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The project name needs to match the name of directory containing the project for Eclipse to automatically include its contents for analysis.

Comment: This is the case but I still have the issue. Any other ideas?